# author name with periods produces Et al

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, capitalization

I want to cite this article:

```
@article{kc2010ppe,
author = {K.C., Samir and Barakat, B. and Goujon, A. and Skirbekk, V. and Sanderson, W. and Lutz, W.},
journal = {Demographic Research},
number = {55},
pages = {383--472},
posted-at = {2012-07-06 13:25:30},
priority = {2},
publisher = {Max Planck Institute for Demographic Research, Rostock, Germany},
title = {{Projection of populations by level of educational attainment, age, and sex for 120 countries for 2005-2050}},
volume = {22},
year = {2010}
}
```

The lead authors name is Samir K.C. (surname is K.C.). I cannot figure out how to get the reference correctly in the text. I am using natbib through biblatex. My .tex file is something like:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true, backend=bibtex8, firstinits=true, style=authoryear-comp, dashed=false, isbn=false, maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}
...
more preamble and the rest of the paper...
...
Global population forecasts, such as \citet{kc2010ppe} or...
```

Which outputs...

> Global population forecasts, such as K.C. Et al. (2010) or ...

Where as I want a lower case e...

> Global population forecasts, such as K.C. et al. (2010) or ...

I suspect this behavior is something to do with the unconventional surname?

Comment: Almost certainly this is the punctuation tracker being caught out by a very unusual name. Have you tried the obvious wrap-in-braces approach?

Comment: yep, I have tried Samir K.{C}. and Samir {K.C.}. Neither have an effect.

Comment: Don't sent a "something like this"-snippet. Make a real, complete, small example that others can use for tests.

Comment: In the cited document, the author's name is repeatedly given as "Samir KC", i.e. without dots. So, why not use this name when referring to the document?

Comment: I know the guy. He prefers K.C.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem can be circumvented by resetting the punctuation tracker

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{kc2010ppe,
author = {K.C.{\midsentence}, Samir and Barakat, B. and Goujon, A. and Skirbekk, V. and Sanderson, W. and Lutz, W.},
journal = {Demographic Research},
number = {55},
pages = {383--472},
posted-at = {2012-07-06 13:25:30},
priority = {2},
publisher = {Max Planck Institute for Demographic Research, Rostock, Germany},
title = {Projection of populations by level of educational attainment, age, and sex for 120 countries for 2005-2050},
volume = {22},
year = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents}  
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}  
\citeauthor{kc2010ppe}
\end{document}
```

---

The `biblatex` team have agreed that this is a bug in the package, and it's fixed in the master sources. Thus the next release to CTAN should remove the issue entirely.

Comment: works a treat. cheers!

Comment: @lockstep Nothing to stop you posting that as a separate answer :-) I think we'll look to revise `biblatex` in any case: the end of a surname can't be the end of a sentence even if it ends `.`.

Answer (score 7):

A shorter workaround is to write the author as `K.C\adddot, Samir`. Quoting section 4.7.3 of the manual:

> `\adddot`
>
> Adds a period unless it is preceded by any punctuation mark. The
>   purpose of this command is inserting the dot after an abbreviation.
>   Any dot inserted this way is recognized as such by the other
>   punctuation commands. This command may also be used to turn a
>   previously inserted literal period into an abbreviation dot.

Comment: Or you can use `\isdot` in the name formatting directives. That is the approach PL actually takes. The bug arose because the `name:last` bibliography macro was missing an `\isdot`.